# Trying to make the embed send privately to a user

Tags: node.js

So I’m basically using guilded.js, and I’m tryna make it so it sends my embed privately to a user who the user meantions.

I got no errors at the moment. I ran my code and didn’t get any error at all so I came here for assistance/.

```
const { Embed } = require("guilded.js");
module.exports = {
  description: "Generates a random insult and sends it as a message. You can mention another user to roast them.",
  aliases: ["insult", "roast"],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    // List of insults
    const insults = [
      "someday you’ll go far. And I really hope you stay there.",
      "your secrets are always safe with me. I never even listen when you tell me them.",
      "i wish I had a flip phone, so I could slam it shut on this conversation.",
      "you have so many gaps in your teeth it looks like your tongue is in jail.",
      "if you have a problem with me, write the problem on a piece of paper, fold it, and shove it up your ass.",
      "light travels faster than sound which is why you seemed bright until you spoke.",
      "if laughter is the best medicine, your face must be curing the world.",
      "i find the fact that you’ve lived this long both surprising and disappointing.",
     
      // more insults...
    ];
    if (!message.mentions) {
      return message.reply("please mention a user to roast.");
    }
    try {
      // Pick a random insult from the list
      const randomInsult = insults[Math.floor(Math.random() * insults.length)];
      // Create an embed
      const embed = new Embed()
        .setColor('#F5C400')
        .setDescription(`<@${message.mentions.users[0].id}> ${randomInsult}`);
      
      // Send the embed
      message.send({ embeds: [embed]});
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // empty catch block
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.